# Fallback page via CloudFront distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I have a simple site `mysite.com` served behind CloudFront distribution and `maintenance.mysite.com` single static page hosted on S3 also served behind CloudFront distribution.

[image: diagram]

I want to be able to switch between them on route53 level when my main site is not available, but CloudFront doesn't allow to have same domain name attached to the different distributions. As per docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html

> Duplicate and overlapping alternate domain names
> You cannot add an alternate domain name to a CloudFront distribution if the same alternate domain name already exists in another CloudFront distribution, even if your AWS account owns the other distribution.

What is the proper and fastest way to switch between main and backup pages on a route53 level?
I don't want extra load balancers / lambdas to be involved and DNS way is the preferable solution.

Comment: I never did that but I was reading about something related to that a few days ago, did you try to set up the S3 endpoint as a fallback distribution on CloudFront? I think with that, CloudFront will route the connections to another distribution if for some reason the primary one is not up. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/high_availability_origin_failover.html

Comment: @Juan Fontes, there is a way to setup a failover, but the issue is that I wouldn't have 4xx/5xx errors for it to be triggered therefore I want a way to trigger that via route53/dns record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no straightforward solution, so I'm posting workarounds from AWS support here as an answer

**Workaround 1:**

You need to have 2 CloudFront distributions. One of these would be “Blue” and the other, “Green”. The Blue distribution would need to have [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com)  as the alternate domain name. Now, create a DNS record that points `www.domain.com` to the CloudFront distribution “Blue” which will act as Production environment now.
Moving on, add the CNAME `*.domain.com` to the CloudFront distribution "Green" (the other distribution).

Now, in this setup, a request to `www.domain.com` would land on the Blue Distribution, as it has `www.domain.com` as the ADN (which is more granular than `*.domain.com`). Now, when you want to make the “Green” distribution as production distribution, just remove the Alternate Domain Name from the "blue" distribution. In that case, there would be only one distribution that would satisfy the request for `www.domain.com`, the Green one (which has `*.domain.com` as ADN), and the request would be routed to that even if your DNS points `www.domain.com`  to the Blue distribution (as CloudFront routes a request based on the Host header and will choose a distribution that has that domain as the ADN).

**Workaround 2**:

You need to have 2 CloudFront distributions. One of these would be “Blue” and the other, “Green”. Create a DNS record that points `www.domain.com` to the CloudFront distribution “Blue” which will act as Production environment now. Also, add `www.domain.com` as a CNAME(Alternate Domain Name) to the distribution “Blue”. Meanwhile you can test the other CloudFront distribution “Green”.

When you want to make the “Green” distribution as production distribution, you should first point the DNS record for `www.domain.com` to the CloudFront distribution “Green”. Even though the DNS points to the “Green” distribution, the request will still be routed to the “Blue" CloudFront distribution because “Blue” CloudFront distribution has the CNAME(Alternate Domain Name) for `www.domain.com`  (CloudFront will try to route the request to a CloudFront distribution that has the same CNAME(Alternate Domain Name) value as the value of the host header). Wait for a few hours for the new DNS record to propagate. Then, remove the CNAME from CloudFront distribution “Blue” and add it immediately to the CloudFront distribution ”Green”. Now all the requests will be routed by CloudFront to the “Green” CloudFront distribution since the “Green” CloudFront distribution has the CNAME(Alternate Domain Name) `www.domain.com`.

This workaround would involve some downtime when you move the CNAME from the "blue" distribution to the "green" distribution, so I would recommend going with the first workaround only. Also, please test this on a test environment first before testing it on the production distributions.

Comment: I have ended up using 1st approach which is a bit inconvenient, but does its job. Second one involves having a longer period of downtime which I think is not suitable at all.

Answer (score 1):

I think this depends on how you want to create [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) vs mysite.com.  If, as you have in your diagram, all incoming requests are actually to mysite.com, then you can just have a CNAME* entry that points mysite.com to www. when that's up and running, and to maintenance. when it's in maintenance mode. However, if you want www. and mysite.com (with no subdomain) to both go to the same place and have that same place switch around, then you need to come up with another name for your production server. Then you can have

```
                                 - prod.mysite.com
                                /
[www.mysite.com | mysite.com] -< CNAME* in Route53
                                \
                                 - maintenance.mysite.com
```

CNAME is the standard DNS way to do this; however, I believe AWS charges for CNAME redirects and not for aliases, So, wherever I say CNAME above, you can actually create an A record in Route53, and then click on the "alias" switch and select "Alias to another record in this hosted zone".

Comment: yes, but Cloudfront distribution for prod (which has mysite.com and www.mysite.com as alternative cnames) would not accept setting same cnames for the maintenance distribution. That's why the question arises. Generally, what you have described is the way

Comment: Hmm. I always do this behind a load balancer, which is much easier :) It appears the issue is the way CloudFront associates CNAMEs to IP addresses at edge distributions. You can get most of the way there with [this](https://serverfault.com/a/752140), but you run the risk that it won't completely fail over because of potential conflicts at the edge.